# Output of Visual Studio unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I would like to know if it's possible to return some kind of value, bool, string or int for example from unit test methods.

For example I have this method:

```
[TestMethod]
public bool TestMetho()
{
    var SY = calc.GetUserInfo(new DateTime(2015, 12, 15));
    bool isOK = Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 11, 29), SY);
    return bool;
}
```

I would like to reference the unit class methods from a console app and then print out the results. Is it possible to do something like this, because at this time I'm not able to assign the `Assert.AreEqual` method to some output variable.

Comment: You can run unit tests from the command prompt using [MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182490.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You sure can.

1. Add a reference to `System.Diagnostics`.
2. Make sure you choose `Debug` when you go to run your test.
3. Use `Debug.WriteLine()`, and you'll be able to see the desired output in the `Debug` window.

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public bool TestMetho()
   {
        var SY = calc.GetUserInfo(new DateTime(2015, 12, 15));
        bool isOK = Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 11, 29), SY);
        Debug.WriteLine("Date Time : {0}", SY)
        return bool;
   }
   ```